# WorldSpace and NodeSpace

Tags: ios, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I think I am not getting what's wolrd space and node space.
I have one node that is a child of a physicsNode. In a method of that node class I have the following code:

```
[self convertToNodeSpace:[self.physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:self.positionInPoints]];
```

I thought I was converting the position of the node (in reference to his parent; the physicsNode) to the worldSpace and then convert this position to the node space. So I should get ccp(0,0). But I got ccp(8.4999,4.0001) no idea why.

If I run this code:

```
[self convertToNodeSpace:[self.physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:ccpAdd(self.positionInPoints,ccp(200,0))]];
```

I get ccp(149.92133046214917,-137.42134383693451).. I would expect to get ccp(200,0). What's going on?

Comment: world space is coordinates relative to the scene's origin (scene.position, usually 0,0) and node space is the coordinates relative to the node parent's origin (node.parent.position)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert back and forth to get a better understanding of world and node space?

I assume following node structure:

- CCPhysicsNode

  - CCNode (You want to get position of this node)

You have placed CCNode at (0,0) and assume that transforming to world space and back to node space should result in (0,0) again?

1. **Get world position**:

   ```
   CGPoint worldPos = [self.physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:self.positionInPoints];
   ```
2. **Convert back to node space:** to convert back to the node space, you need to use the **`physicsNode`** because `self` is a child of the `physicsNode`:

   ```
   CGPoint nodePos = [self.physicsNode convertToNodeSpace:worldPos];
   ```